# Passing an array into hidden_field ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hidden-field

I'm trying to pass an array into a hidden_field.

The following User has 3 roles [2,4,5]

```
>> u = User.find_by_login("lesa")
=> #<User id: 5, login: "lesa", email: "lesa.beaupry@gmail.com", crypted_password: "0f2776e68f1054a2678ad69a3b28e35ad9f42078", salt: "f02ef9e00d16f1b9f82dfcc488fdf96bf5aab4a8", created_at: "2009-12-29 15:15:51", updated_at: "2010-01-06 06:27:16", remember_token: nil, remember_token_expires_at: nil>
>> u.roles.map(&:id)
=> [2, 4, 5]
```

Users/edit.html.erb

```
<% form_for @user do |f| -%>
<%= f.hidden_field :role_ids, :value => @user.roles.map(&:id) %>
```

When I submit my edit form, I receive an error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#update "**Couldn't find Role with ID=245**"

How can I pass an array into the hidden_field?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I would use this technique.

```
<% @user.roles.each do |role| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :role_ids, :multiple => true, :value => role.id %>
<% end %>
```

`:multiple` adds both the `[]` to the end of the name attribute and `multiple="multiple"` to the input element, which is ideal. Rails uses this internally when it generates inputs for arrays, such as in `fields_for`.

Unfortunately it is not well-documented. I'm going to look into fixing this.

Comment: This does work in Rails 4 altho it generates inputs with the same id.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Rails 4.0.2 when using `form_tag` with `hidden_field_tag`, I would only get the last role in `params[:role_ids]`. Using `hidden_field_tag 'role_ids[]'` works fine.

Comment: @JeremyF. It won't work with `hidden_field_tag`, it has to be `hidden_field`.

Comment: If you do want to use hidden_field_tag, then `<%= hidden_field_tag('role_ids[]', role.id) %>`

Comment: Is there now documentation? If yes, could you give me a link? Thanks

Answer (score 17):

The only thing that works for me (Rails 3.1) is using hidden_field_tag:

```
<% @users.roles.each do |role| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user_role_ids[]", role.id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The double quotes around user_role_ids[] are important. Single quotes didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 <% @user.roles.each_with_index do |role| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "role_ids[]", :value => role.id %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: that seems to make a hash - perhaps I'll hack around with it.

Comment: This is close, What ended up working was...<% f.fields_for :users do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'user_fields', :f => builder %>
<% end %> THEN <% role = Role.find(:first) %>
<%= f.hidden_field :role_ids, :value => role.id %>

Comment: This is how it worked for me ` <% @user.roles.each do |role| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field "role_ids][", :value => role.id %>
 <% end %>` .... Remember to reverse the brackets for role_ids][. If  I don't reverse the brackets I get nil in the array for role_ids param in my server logs, with reverse brackets it works like charm. Don't know why it works, it would be great if somebody could explain it.

Answer (score 3):

using Rails 4.2.6

I was able to use

```
<% @user.roles.each do |role|
  <%= f.hidden_field :role_ids, :id => role.id, :value => role.id, :multiple => true %>
<% end %>
```

which rendered:

```
<input id="12345" value="12345" multiple="multiple" type="hidden" name="role_form[role_ids][]">
```

trying to use `hidden_field_tag` or the `'role_ids[]'` the param details were not being included in my `form_params`.

This didn't work:

```
<% @user.roles.each do |role|
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'role_ids[]', role %>
<% end %>
```

because it renders:

```
<input type="hidden" name="role_ids[]" id="role_ids_" value="12345">
```

and is seen by the controller **outside** of the form params.

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :role_ids, :value => @user.roles.map(&:id).join(", ") %>
```

edit: note - you'll need to do `ids.split(", ")` in your controller to convert them from a string into an array

Comment: Close but it still doesn't work. 

Required Output: "role_ids"=>["2", "4"]
Actual Output: "role_ids"=>"2, 4"

Comment: Still, I found this to be the best solution, just naming the hidden field something like `:concatenated_role_ids` instead and adding something like `params[:role_ids] ||= params.require(:concatenated_role_ids).split(', ')` to the top of the controller action.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the original question involved a Rails `form_for` form, but I just encountered this problem while trying adding a hidden field to a `form_tag` form. The solution is slightly different.

The `hidden_field_tag` kept converting my ids to a space-separated string, like `"1 2 3"`, not the array of `["1", "2", "3"]` that I wanted.  According to [the docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag), this is a known problem with `hidden_field_tag`. This is the approach that ended up working for my Rails 6 `form_tag` form:

In the view:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :role_ids, my_role_ids_array %>
```

In the controller:

```
role_ids = params[:role_ids].split(' ').map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could solve this kind of issue with :

```rb
      <% params[:filter].each do |filter| %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'filter[]', filter %>
      <% end %>
```