# Passing an array through a hidden_field_tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, parameters, hidden-fields

I did find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015204/passing-an-array-into-hidden-field-ror) on SO, but it didn't help, really.

So, I'd like to pass an array through a hidden field tag. 
As of now my code is:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "article_ids", @articles.map(&:id) %>
```

This obviously does not work since it passes the ids as a string.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Hi maybe there is better solution but you may try

```
<% @articles.map(&:id).each do |id| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "article_ids[]", id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me on Rails 4.1.10

```
<% @your_array.map().each do |array_element| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "your_array[]", array_element %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to parse it to and from json:

```
articles_list = @articles.map(&:id).to_json # gives u: [1,2,3,4,5]
                                            # note that the result is a string instead of an array
article_ids = JSON.parse(articles_list)
```

Or you could just make use of comma separated string:

```
articles_list = @articles.map(&:id).join(",") # gives u: 1,2,3,4,5
                                              # note that this result is a string also
article_ids = articles_list.split(/,/).map(&:to_i)
```

Answer (score 1):

On Rails 4 you can do:

```
<% @articles.map(&:id).each do |id| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "article_ids", value: id, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

As Rails will automatically append "[]" to the name of the field (when using `multiple`) and the controller that receives the form will see that as an array of values.

Comment: hm, this doesnt work for me at all, it will result in a parameter `"article_ids"=>"{:value=>123, :multiple=>true}"`

Comment: @Ninigi I lost the code to test the output, can you try `<%= hidden_field "article_ids", id, multiple: true %>` and see if it works then I'll update the answer? (using `hidden_field` helper and without `value:`)

Comment: doesnt work either, it just ignores the multiple option. I've taken a small look at the code for the hidden_field helper. In the end, it uses the generic `tag` method and I did not find anything about multiple. Maybe this is deprecated?

Comment: Make sure to include a `hidden_field_tag` with an empty Array or nil value, otherwise, there will be no way for the User to "uncheck" all the values.